# react-admin, component ReferenceArrayInput can not set default value (pre selected items)

Tags: react-admin

for the last version of react-admin, i use ReferenceArrayInput to select mutilple items, but before select, we need show pre selected value, i use the property of defaultValue and initialValue to set selected ids, but these not working, how to solve it?

```
<ReferenceArrayInput source="userIds" reference="users" defaultValue={[1,2,3]}>
  <AutocompleteArrayInput source="userIds" label="user" optionText="name" />
</ReferenceArrayInput>
```

i use initialValue, but not work

Comment: Can you try setting `defaultValue` on `<AutocompleteArrayInput>` rather than `<ReferenceArrayInput>`?